# How to search and replace pattern in a text file using a script in Ubuntu

Tags: python, regex, bash, shell, grep

I have following text in the file:

```
@XmlElement(namespace = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:icalendar-2.0", required = true)
```

I want to replace this with:

```
@Namespace(reference="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:icalendar-2.0")
@Element(required = true)
```

I want to replace all the occurrences also.

Please suggest how to do this in a script to run on multiple files.

Comment: Are you on Linux? You could do this in a Linux shell with the `sed` command pretty easily.

Comment: Basic search/replace, bad question for SO and Python. sed, regex, basic string manip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux you could do something like this in a shell:

```
sed 's/@XmlElement(namespace = \(".*"\), \(required = true\))/@Namespace(reference=\1)\n@Element(\2)/' files
```

Note that the `files` at the end would be the names of your files, or a pattern, like `*.txt`. You can add a `-i` after `sed` (leave a space between them) to edit the files 'in place', meaning the files will actually be edited. You should back up the files first, as this will change them. You can also throw an extension after the `-i`, as in `-ibak`, which should create backups of each file with a `.bak` extension as it works, but double check that your version of sed does this (i.e. `man sed` and read up on `-i`).